# pointSize property in SceneKit being Ignored

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to render a point cloud using SceneKit (ultimately for ARKit). However, I'm finding the `pointSize` (and `minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius`) properties are ignored when trying to modify the `SCNGeometryElement`. There was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41669553/3333201) solution to call on the underlying OpenGL property, but this seems to work only in simulation. 
No matter what `pointSize` I put in, the points are the same size. This is roughly how my code is laid out. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my `GeometryElement` setup?

```
  var index: Int = 0  
    for x_pos in stride(from: start , to: end, by: increment) {  
        for y_pos in stride(from: start , to: end, by: increment) {  
            for z_pos in stride(from: start , to: end, by: increment) {  
                let pos:SCNVector3 = SCNVector3(x: x_pos, y: y_pos, z: z_pos)  
                positions.append(pos)  
                normals.append(normal)  
                indices.append(index)  
                index = index + 1  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    let pt_positions : SCNGeometrySource = SCNGeometrySource.init(vertices: positions)  
    let n_positions: SCNGeometrySource = SCNGeometrySource.init(normals: normals)  

    let pointer = UnsafeRawPointer(indices)  
    let indexData = NSData(bytes: pointer, length: MemoryLayout<Int32>.size * indices.count)  

    let elements = SCNGeometryElement(data: indexData as Data, primitiveType: .point, primitiveCount: positions.count, bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)  
    elements.pointSize = 10.0 //being ignored  
    elements.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 10 //also being ignored  
    let pointCloud = SCNGeometry (sources: [pt_positions, n_positions], elements: [elements])  
    pointCloud.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = SCNMaterial.LightingModel.constant  


    let ptNode = SCNNode(geometry: pointCloud)  
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ptNode)
```

Comment: are you using SceneKit's Metal renderer? That is `SCNRenderingAPIMetal` which is the default on device (the iOS simulator doesn't support Metal) and without the [`PrefersOpenGL`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1904/_index.html) setting.

Comment: Oh! So that works! I was using the Metal Renderer instead of OpenGL. Once I set PrefersOpenGL to Yes, the glPointSize command worked fine. This makes sense. 
Question though: How does one change the particle size on the default Metal renderer?

Comment: I meant that you *should* use the Metal renderer. `pointSize` and `minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius` only apply to the Metal renderer and I wanted to make sure that you don't use OpenGL.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean. So I did not have any `PrefersOpenGL` settings initially. I assume it defaulted to Metal. Is there any other way to make sure of this?

Comment: you can ask the view for its [`renderingAPI`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522616-renderingapi). You can also set the [`showsStatistics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1522763-showsstatistics) property and the statistics bar will display either "GL" (for OpenGL) or "Mt" (for Metal).

Comment: Thanks. This was incredibly useful. `showsStatistics` definitely says Mt, but the `pointSize` is still being ignored.

Comment: @pj_mukh Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @AlexanderofNorway, so I switched to using raw Metal GPU calls to work around this issue. HOWEVER, as off iOS13 I have heard pointSize does work as long as you also set minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius.

I haven't had a chance to try it myself, but I will.

Comment: Yup, as off iOS13 the accepted solution below works

Comment: @pj_mukh Thanks for the quick answer! It does works with metal now.. I just hadn`t checked that pointSize = 1 is the default... so it didn't change when setting to that... (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should also specify both element.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius and element.maximumPointScreenSpaceRadius. if so your point size work! :)